# How to move my pandas dataframe to d3?

Tags: pandas, d3.js, ipython, data-munging

I am new to Python and have worked my way through a few books on it. Everything is great, except visualizations. I really dislike matplotlib and Bokeh requires too heavy of a stack.

The workflow I want is:

Data munging analysis using pandas in ipython notebook -> visualization using d3 in sublimetext2

However, being new to both Python and d3, I don't know the best way to export my pandas dataframe to d3. Should I just have it as a csv? JSON? Or is there a more direct way?

Side question: Is there any (reasonable) way to do everything in an ipython notebook instead of switching to sublimetext?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's `df.to_json` or `df.to_csv` for moving the data around. There's [vincent](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent) for a python -> vega translator (it supports DataFrames well). And another project of Rob's, [sticky](https://github.com/wrobstory/sticky), is in alpha, but it sounds like what you want for not leaving the IPython notebook.

Comment: I know you said you dislike matplotlib, but have you looked at [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io)? It's quite nice, I've had a recent success using it to make an online interactive plot.

Answer (score 5):

Basically there is no best format what will fit all your visualization needs.

It really depends on the visualizations you want to obtain.

For example, a [Stacked Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3886208/) takes as input a CSV file, and an [adjacency matrix vizualisation](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables) takes a JSON format.

From my experience:

- to display relations beetween items, like [adjacency matrix](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables) or [chord diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006), one will prefer a JSON format that will allow to describe only existing relations. Data are stored like in a sparse matrix, and several data can be nested using dictionary. Moreover this format can directly be parsed in Python.
- to display properties of an array of items, a CSV format can be fine. A perfect example can be found [here](http://exposedata.com/parallel) with a parallel chart display.
- to display hierarchical data, like a tree, JSON is best suited.

The best thing to do to help you figure out what best format you need, is to have a look at this  [d3js gallery](https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery)

Comment: So basically the takeaway is that there is no "best" way to move data between them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use D3 directly inside of Jupyter / Ipython. Try the two links below ..

http://blog.thedataincubator.com/2015/08/embedding-d3-in-an-ipython-notebook/

https://github.com/cmoscardi/embedded_d3_example/blob/master/Embedded_D3.ipynb